# How to guarantee that messages received by server are from a client running my app?

Tags: security, encryption, cryptography, client-server, message

I'm wondering how I can guarantee that messages received by the server are definitely from a client that is running my app on their smartphone.

Messages sent by clients running my app will be secured by SSL encryption, so would a good solution be to include some sort of secret key that is stored on the device and on the server, that is then embedded within the message body? (but then this key is prone to being discovered through reverse engineering)

Comment: Protocol related questions really belong on http://security.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 1):

Well, no, if you cannot trust your code and if you do not have access to some kind of protected key store (that performs it's own encryption, e.g. a TPM or suchlike) then anybody can steal the key. If you require authentication you can of course use the normal authentication methods such as user passwords.

If you require the messages to be protected you can then derive a key from the password (using a PBKDF such as PBKDF2 for instance), decrypt a private key with it and use it to sign the messages. If that's too slow, you can use the private key to encrypt a session key, and use a message authentication code.